# How to use filter for field in django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Hello
How to I'm can use template filter for some field in django-admin?
I'm have read-only TextField and want use |linebreaks for this field, how to I'm can enable this?
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [custom widget](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) for this field and set it to [work with this field](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides).